# Why does this code cause page faults?

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I allocate 512mb of memory, and then I modify every 4096th byte (this should cause minor page fault for each modification, and that's what I actually get). But then I repeat the same loop, and it again causes minor page fault for each request. My question is, why?

Output looks like this:

[image]

However, if I remove calling ps from my program, the time needed to execute second loop is much lower, like 0.04s. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

const int sz = 512 * 1024 * 1024;

int main()
{
    char * data = (char *)malloc(sz);
    if (data == 0) cout << "alloc fail";
    stringstream cmd;
    cmd << "ps -o min_flt,maj_flt " << getpid();
    system(cmd.str().c_str());
    cout << "start\n";
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i=0; i<sz; i += 4096)
        data[i] = 1;
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time1 = double(end-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    system(cmd.str().c_str());

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i += 4096)
        data[i] = 1;
    end = clock();
    double time2 = double(end-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    system(cmd.str().c_str());

    cout << time1 << " " << time2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc()` instead of `new()`?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<sz; i += 4096)  data[i] = 1;` you should make sure your index is in range

Comment: Presumably because setting up a shell and then getting it to invoke `ps` uses enough memory that the system pages out some of your newly-created pages. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 2 Gb, and judging from the fact that in most of runs almost all page faults are minor, swapping is not the cause (if it was, I'd get mostly major page faults).

Comment: @billz, index is in range.

Comment: @πάνταῥε, using new instead of malloc doesn't change the results.

Comment: @frp _"doesn't change the results. "_  I don't doubt so. But for c++ code you should use `new()`, or even better a `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @frp: By the way, on linux you can read process statistics directly from `/proc/self/stat`; `minflt` and `majflt` are (currently) the 10th and 12th elements in the returned line (which is a series of space-separated fields, intended to be read with `scanf`). See `man 5 proc` for the list of fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library function `system` does roughly the following:

1. Fork, creating a new process with a duplicate of the memory image.
2. In the child, `exec` `/bin/sh` passing it the command-line option `-c` and the indicated command, replacing the memory image of the new process with a newly-loaded /bin/sh.
3. In the parent (the original process), wait for the child to finish, and return its status code.

When a process executes `fork`, the system wants to avoid copying the entire memory image in order to duplicate it. So it just duplicates the page tables, and marks all the pages as "copy-on-write" which requires setting them to read-only so that writes can be detected.

The subsequent `exec` will mark the pages as unshared, but it probably will not cancel the setting of the pages as read-only so that subsequent writes to the pages will still trigger a minor page fault, although the handler will do nothing since the page is no longer shared.

It is not actually guaranteed that the `exec` will happen before the second write loop starts. Your machine most likely has more than one core, so it is quite possible for both processes to be simultaneously active. Since the `exec` might take a while to set up, it is quite possible that some of the write loop will happen even before the `exec`, which is to say before there was any clue that the copy-on-write was unnecessary.